# Can't boot into Ubuntu after installing alongside Windows on Dell Inspiron 3542

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, dell, windows-10

Today I installed Ubuntu on a partition on my Hard drive, which already had Windows 10 installed. When I boot up my laptop Windows Boot Manager automatically boots into Windows. I have heard that I need to enable GRUB but I'm not even sure how I can get back into Ubuntu. I tried enabling UEFI in boot options but I can only see Windows Boot Manager and not an option to boot into the Ubuntu partition. Any help would be great.

Comment: If Windows is UEFI which all new systems are, you want to be sure to install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode. And how you boot install media UEFI or BIOS/Legacy is how it installs. If you installed in BIOS/Legacy mode, you can use Boot-Repair's advanced mode to totally reinstall grub if you boot it in UEFI mode.

Answer (score 0):

Enable legacy support in bios. Then go to boot order and put usb first. Reboot. Hit f12 for boot options. Select usb and it should boot.

Comment: Oh im sorry i see now you put it on your hard drive. In that case just enable legacy support in bios. Reboot. Hit f12 and boot the linux os.